# MySQL Query Doubling Sums

Tags: mysql

I am designing a query to retrieve the sum of labor hours for a given period, this query works beautifully except when I get to this sonum. All of the values are doubled. I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong. If I do not join the tables this does not occur. Any help?

```
SELECT UPPER(`2016`.sonum) as sonum, SUM(`2016`.lbrhrs) as 'lbrhrs', SUM(`2016`.burhrs) as 'burhrs', MONTH(`2016`.date) as 'date', `2016`.dept as dept, closedates.closedate as 'closed date'
FROM `2016`
LEFT JOIN closedates on UPPER(`2016`.sonum)=UPPER(closedates.sonum)
WHERE `2016`.sonum=3470 and month(`2016`.`date`)=1
GROUP BY UPPER(`2016`.sonum), `2016`.dept, month(`2016`.date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *this* case, there is an easy workaround to the "explode-implode" problem that happens with `JOIN` + `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  UPPER(`2016`.sonum) as sonum,
        SUM(`2016`.lbrhrs) as 'lbrhrs',
        SUM(`2016`.burhrs) as 'burhrs',
        MONTH(`2016`.date) as 'date',
        `2016`.dept as dept,
        ( SELECT MAX(closedate)
              FROM closedates
              WHERE sonum = `2016`.sonum   -- see note below
        ) as 'closed date'   -- Here's the trick
    FROM  `2016`
    WHERE  `2016`.sonum=3470
      and  month(`2016`.`date`)=1
    GROUP BY  UPPER(`2016`.sonum),
              `2016`.dept,
              month(`2016`.date);
```

If `sonum` has any `..._ci` collation, then it is "Case Insensitive", so the `UPPER()` is unnecessary for comparing.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

The 'trick' is to avoid the `JOIN`, thereby avoiding the multiplication of rows before doing the `SUMs`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm rather new to SQL obviously and concepts like this really help my understanding. I was making a program to dump and parse this stuff, so I just added a query to pull the latest close date and kill the rest before I ran the problematic query.

Comment: Oh, then you probably need `( SELECT MAX(closedate) ...)` for the subquery.  I'll change that.

Answer (score 0):

Check your joined table for multiple records for a single sonum.
This would be one of the first things that I would check when debugging your query.

If there are more than 1 record per sonum in your closedates table, you will need to see how you might filter down those records to only include 1 record for each sonum from the closedates table.

Sample data and table layout from your db would help to answer this more completely.
hth

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: (shameful plea) can you vote my answer up for you if it helped?

Comment: Can't, I don't have enough reputation. Would if I could though!